# Putting a span with an image before the text of a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I have an HTML structure that looks like this:

```
<li class="thing"><a href="#" class="my-link">Something</a></li>
```

My goal is to put a span that looks like this in front of the link tag:

`<span class="my-span"></span>`

What's the best way to go about doing this? Is it a CSS `:before` or a jQuery/Zepto `.before` method? Also, proper syntax as to how to do this would be helpful. I've been struggling with this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be better to give each element an id, searching element by class name may give you multiple results if elements share same class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('<span class="my-span"></span>').insertBefore('.my-link');`

Check more details from [.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need that `<span>` to be generated `dynamically` you may go for `Jquery` `.before()`

You may find for information in the following link with exaples

http://api.jquery.com/before/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with Javascript. (Tried on FireBug for Firefox)

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("my-link")
//Now a[0] will have your first link
b = document.createElement("span") //Your new span element
b.setAttribute("class","my-span")
a[0].parentElement.insertBefore(b,a[0])
```

Does this help? Or did you want to do it in jQuery?

Information source [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).